# Retrieve elements from data table and sum the same elements

Tags: php, database, woocommerce

I have the table "orders" from woocommerce. 
I filtered and get sorted the elements by status with *GET* request. 
The results are copied to a *JSON* file.

So now, I want to find the elements with the same "product_id" and their values and summarize them to display in screen so I can print them.

**For example:**

"product_id": 45329,
                "variation_id": 0,
                "quantity": 1

"product_id": 48911,
                "variation_id": 0,
                "quantity": 1,

"product_id": 45329,
                "variation_id": 0,
                "quantity": 1

**The output that I want to achieve is this:**

45329 quantity 2
48911 quantity 1

Thanks!

Comment: Why not sum them in the SQL  you execute instead of just filtering and sorting?  `SELECT product_ID, variation_ID, Sum(Quantity) Quantity from woocommerce group by product_ID, Variation_ID ORDER BY Quantity Desc`  but if you don't need variation_ID then don't select it or group by it.

Comment: Because i want to attach PHP code to a custom made php file that produces me a list of the daily orders, but it is not summarize the quantities.

Comment: You are already executing SQL from your php to get your daily orders. Now, from the same php, execute another sql to get your summary level data.

Comment: Or use `with rollup` command so you get both the raw data and the summarize data and display what's needed.  [DOCs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)  Saves a trip but depending on columns returned, you may get back more data than needed; unless you filter out the nulls using a having or something.

Comment: I will try to explain better. I don't want to ask the DB straight because anyone who has access to my DB can get this information. I would like to do it with API so this is the reason I need to write it in PHP.

Comment: What is your JSON data? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean to send all the data from JSON file?
its impossible because everyday they updated with new

Comment: @TasosSeit *...  that produces me a list of the daily orders ...* - what is the format of this information - JSON, array, or something else? Thanks.

Comment: yes, It is a JSON array format. with many tags and values. 
So, from this JSON array I want to call some tags and their values to represent in my browser, using a specific REST API link. This call from JSON array must be with PHP.

Comment: The data I receive in JSON format are given by WooCoomerce REST API.

Comment: @TasosSeit Updated answer. I use List orders GET request from https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders as an example for JSON data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode JSON with `json_decode()` and make calculations. Next example uses simplified  JSON data, which I think matches the format from WooCommerce (I guess this format is from list orders GET request):

```
<?php
# JSON
$json = '
[
  {
    "id": 727,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "id": 315,
        "name": "Woo Single #1",
        "product_id": 93,
        "variation_id": 0,
        "quantity": 2,
        "tax_class": "",
        "subtotal": "6.00",
        "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
        "total": "6.00",
        "total_tax": "0.45",
        "taxes": [
          {
            "id": 75,
            "total": "0.45",
            "subtotal": "0.45"
          }
        ],
        "meta_data": [],
        "sku": "",
        "price": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 316,
        "name": "Ship Your Idea &ndash; Color: Black, Size: M Test",
        "product_id": 22,
        "variation_id": 23,
        "quantity": 1,
        "tax_class": "",
        "subtotal": "12.00",
        "subtotal_tax": "0.90",
        "total": "12.00",
        "total_tax": "0.90",
        "taxes": [
          {
            "id": 75,
            "total": "0.9",
            "subtotal": "0.9"
          }
        ],
        "meta_data": [
          {
            "id": 2095,
            "key": "pa_color",
            "value": "black"
          },
          {
            "id": 2096,
            "key": "size",
            "value": "M Test"
          }
        ],
        "sku": "Bar3",
        "price": 12
      }
    ]
  }
]';
$input = json_decode($json, true);

# Sum
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $order) {
    foreach ($order["line_items"] as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $quantity   = $item['quantity'];
        if (!array_key_exists($product_id, $output)) {
            $output[$product_id] = 0;
        }   
        $output[$product_id] += $quantity;
    }   
}

#Output
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' quantity '.$value.'<br>';
}   
?>
```

Output:

```
93 quantity 2
22 quantity 1
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! but it seems to me by your answer that i have to copy+paste the new orders every day from the json file. I want to do it dynamically. I want the new orders to be inserted in PHP code dynamically and not mannualy.  Also can I filter the orders by status and dont see every order?

Comment: @TasosSeit Of course it's impossible to copy and paste orders. This is just for this example. You receive this data in JSON format, so just decode it.